# Trying to remove border from Twitter Timeline

Tags: html, twitter

i am currently putting together my Uni website and i am adding the Twitter Timeline widget. I have managed to remove that back ground but having trouble trying to remove the 1px border around the widget. Any help??

```
<div style="height: 350px; background-color: white; position: relative; padding: 0px;"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="//twitter.com/handle/my-list" data-dnt="true" data-widget-id="340404022915784704" data-chrome="noheader nofooter">Tweets from @edgehillsu</a> <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); // ]]></script> </div>
```

This is the code, thanks in advance.

http://esu.unioncloud.org/

Answer (score 4):

No css hacking is required to remove the border, you can use Twitters 'Client Side Options'

You just need to add the following attribute to the `<a>` tag in the widget code: `data-chrome="noborders"`

For example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/userName" data-widget-id="0000000000000" data-chrome="noborders">
```

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you [css file](http://esu.unioncloud.org/themes/esu_default/stylesheets/style.css):

```
#twitter-widget-0 {
border: 0;
}
```

Or in your html page:

```
<style type="text/css">
#twitter-widget-0 {
border: 0;
}
</style>
```

Or inside your script:

```
$("#twitter-widget-0").css("border", "0px");
```

Comment: every time i paste it and update, when i go back in, it has disappeared? thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. Now copy and paste the style into the `<style type="text/css">` tags `</style>` and before the `</ head>`.

Comment: <div style="height: 350px; background-color: white; position: relative; padding: 0px;"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="//twitter.com/handle/my-list" data-dnt="true" data-widget-id="340404022915784704" data-chrome="noheader nofooter">Tweets from @edgehillsu</a>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// ]]></script>
</div>


this is what i am looking at.

Comment: Try with this:
`<script type="text/javascript">$("#twitter-widget-0").css("border", "0px");</script>`

Answer (score 0):

The border you see is inside iframe, so you have to remove border inside iframe.

```
.customisable-border {
    border: medium none;
}
```

This removes border.

Mauro